# Who are Cally Bhur and the Brown Man?

Tags: character-identification, hellboy

In *Hellboy Vol. 9: The Wild Hunt*, a troll exclaims to Hellboy,

> Murderous Bastard. How much golden blood on your hands now? Cally Bhur, The Brown Man, The Bog Roosh--

The Bog Roosh had a major role in *Strange Places*, but I don't recognize the other two names. Did these characters ever make an appearance, and if so, in which issue(s)?

Answer (score 1):

In the folklore of the Anglo-Scottish border the Brown Man of the Muirs is a dwarf who serves as a guardian spirit of wild animals.

Comment: Is there any evidence that is related?

Answer (score 0):

Cally bhur is actually called cailleach bheur who is the queen of winter and also a hag as well, some say she is the goddess of highlands and mountains, she is the incarnation of winter itself and rival with the queen of may, who symbolizes fertility and growths, she is a mother with a basket of fruit and flowers while cailleach is a crone, who symbolizes death, always have a basket of brambles and scythes.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this you can [edit] in and how does it relate to _Hellboy_?

Comment: I've not read it personally, but apparently the Cailleach Bheur does appear in one of the Hellboy anthologies: https://hellboy.fandom.com/wiki/Hellboy:_Odd_Jobs